# Determine the isomorphism class of $\mathbb Z^3 / M$ for the subgroup $M$ of $\mathbb Z^3$generated by $(13,9,2),(29,21,5),(2,2,2)$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, integer-lattices

[image]

The problem seems not so hard. My confusion rise from the statement in the solution above that "This question is equivalent to reducing the matrix via **row and column operations**".

Please see the above picture.

I understand row-operation is valid, since it's just changing the base of $M$. However, I cannot understand why we can also take column-operations.

Please help!

Comment: I think the answer  is that students doing this question are expected to know the theorem that states that you can determine the isomorphism class of a quotient of a free abelian group by diagonalizing the associated matrix using  doing unimodular row and columns operations. (Unimodular means that the operations must be invertible over the integers. So you are not allowed multiply a row by $2$, for example, because $2^{-1} \not\in {\mathbb Z}$.)

Comment: I just hope someone can make a more rigorous argument.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually allowed column operations in this situation, because $\mathbb{Z}^{3}$ admits an automorphism permuting the three copies of $\mathbb{Z}$; thus
$\mathbb{Z}^{3}/<(13,9,2), (29,21,5), (2,2,2)> \simeq \mathbb{Z}^{3}/<(9,13,2),(21,29,5), (2,2,2)>$
and so on.

You normally don't want to use column operations on a matrix, because it is equivalent to renaming your "variables" which can be confusing. But since the "variables" correspond to the 3 copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ which all play the same role, there is no problem here.

Comment: Thank you. But, I think column operations is not only permuting the columns , but also some operations such as "the first column minus two times the second column". How to explain this?

Comment: @Henry Yes you are allowed to add an integer multiple of one row or column to another row or column. This is standard theory that you need to learn about.

Comment: @Derek Holt  Great! could you please told me the name of this standard theory or the book where I can find it?